# Change the name of the route in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, router

Change the name of the route in Magento 2
For example http://magento2.loc/checkout changed to http://magento2.loc/supercheckout

Thank you for answer.

Comment: Let us know if [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/routing.html) helps.

Answer (score 1):

Routes are configured in route configuration. In frontend area (storefront) firstpart of url is frontName. To modify frontName of checkout route add following file in your `<ModuleFolder>/etc/frontend/routes.xml`:

```
<config>
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="checkout" frontName="supercheckout" />
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: This doesn't work since the XML expects `<route>` to have a child called `<module>`